# Likes implemented with OG is not showing on Timelines

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am facing problem with FB likes implemented with OG tags. When someone likes my website page it displays the newsfeed in my FB account (if liked by one of my friend). However, the problem is that feed does not display on my Friend's Timelines. It has been tried by 2-3 friends of mine and it does not display on their timelines although it displays in my newsfeeds that my friends has liked this link. Here is the code i am using for OG meta tags.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="News &amp; Updates | The Art of Convergence | Sponsored by amdocs" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/news/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/artslogo2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename" />
<meta property="og:description" content="desp." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="361690510529034" />
```

What can be the issue with this, Even if i liked the url myself, it does not display on my timelines.

Please Suggest ?

Thanks
Zack

Comment: Continue from my above comment, if i like it myself then it displays on my activitylogs however on my timelines, from my activitylogs i have made that activity as Public, but still it doesn't displays on my timelines. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has changed the behaviour of tje like button. Now if you want the link to appear on your timeline or on your friends' news feed, you need to add a comment aftrr you click the like button. AFAIK, theres no way to change this. At least using the like button. You may try using a cusyom share button though.